# How to remove the horizontal white lines in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have updated to visual studio 2017 15.8 yesterday and found that my some of my fields, methods and classes have strange eye-straining white lines that look like this...

[image]

So I wanted to know how to disable them completely?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Uncheck "Show Procedure line separators"

Comment: Thanks so much! I have been struggling with this problem for 24 hours! Thanks again!

Comment: I did it too, quite buried into the options, I spent like half an hour trying to find it yesterday.

Comment: interesting, I did the update and haven't seen this, but +1 for sharing the solution.